# How to organise data when populating UICollectionView with images using Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, uicollectionview

I'm new to Swift, and coding in general, and have been working on a project where I'd like to create a UICollectionView populated with images from Firebase.

Each section of the UICollectionView would be a category, and each category would contain images related to that category. Each UICollectionView belongs to a parent, and I need to keep track of which parent has which categories, and which images are in each category.

To track the parents, categories, and images, I've set up the Firebase database in the following way (with bowl being the parent, the names of fruit as categories, and the keys are references to image data stored elsewhere in the database):

```
"bowl" : {
        "apple" : {
            "-LOM1R4EH9nszjJp0Va5" : true,
            "-LOM1aRZT2XCE-6fvLBK" : true,
            "-LOM1hSTmRY6wGrWMvIo" : true,
            "-LOM1xnvKE6lc7fizomh" : true
        },
        "banana" : {
            "-LOLmQWLXXyiCUwDBwID" : true
        },
        "pear" : {
            "-LOLHakW-EtqevCeHfzl" : true,
            "-LOM2DBGGuX5VQLmBz46" : true
        },
        "orange" : {
            "-LOM26_pm6lbJ1D6hVPB" : true
        }
    }
```

The image data section of the database looks as follows:

```
    "image" : {
        "fruit" : {
            "-LOLHakW-EtqevCeHfzl" : {
                "description" : "round orange",
                "imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/1/image1"
            },
            "-LOLmQWLXXyiCUwDBwID" : {
                "description" : "big banana",
                "imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/1/image2"
            },
            "-LOM1R4EH9nszjJp0Va5" : {
                "description" : "small apple",
                "imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/1/image3"
            }
        }
    }
```

The approach I have been attempting to take is to create a dictionary with the image keys in it, then iterate through the image keys to grab the image data associated with each key (such as the imageURL), and then use the imageURL to download the images and populate the UICollectionView.

I've created a struct, as follows to transform the image data:

```
struct FruitPicture {
        let imageURL: String
        let description: String
        init(imageURL: String, description: String) {
            self.imageURL = imageURL
            self.description = description
        }
        init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            guard
                let value = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject],
                let imageURL = value["imageURL"] as? String,
                let description = value["description"] as? String else {
                    return nil
            }
            self.imageURL = imageURL
            self.description = description
        }
        func toAnyObject() -> Any {
            return [
                "imageURL": imageURL,
                "description": description
            ]
        }
    }
```

I've been able to gather the imageURLs and populate a UICollectionView but it doesn't include the category details, and so far has involved a lot of manipulation of the data via snapshots, dictionaries, arrays, arrays of dictionaries, and so on, from one configuration to another and back again, and I've now become stuck and confused.

I've started looking at using multiple structs and nesting one within the other, like so, but I'm muddled on it all and am spending hours getting nowhere:

```
struct Picture {
    var url: URL
    var image: UIImage?
}

struct PictureCategory {
    var name: String
    var pictures: [Picture]
}
```

I was hoping for some advice, or roadmap, or details of how you would approach this, or some sample code, or anything to point me in the right direction. Thanks.

**Edit to add more info**

Thank you Iraniya your reply was very helpful and helped me consider things in a different way, I really appreciate it.

Taking your advice I've written the following which looks up a bowling creates a snapshot of the image meta data within (e.g the fruit and keys associated with that fruit) then uses those keys to create a snapshot of the image data (e.g key, imageURL, description). I then transform both snapshots into dictionaries, and return the dictionaries to the method which called it:

```
// GET DATA
static func getPicData(forKey bowlKey: String, completion: @escaping ([String : [Any]], [String : [FruitPicture]]) -> Void) {

    var imageMetaDict: [String : [Any]] = [:]
    var imageDataDict: [String : [FruitPicture]] = [:]

    // DEFINE DATABASE TARGET
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("meta").child("bowl").child(bowlKey).child("fruit")

    // GET DATA INTO SNAPSHOT AND TRANSFORM INTO DICTIONARY
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:[String:Any]] else {
            return completion([:],[:])
        }

        // DEFINE DISPATCH GROUP
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        // ITERATAE THROUGH DICTIONARY
        for (categoryObject, fruitData) in dict {

            // CREATE ARRAY TO STORE ITEMS
            var itemArray = [String]()

            // ITERATE THROUGH ITEMS IN FRUIT DATA
            for item in fruitData {

                // APPEND ITEM.KEY TO ITEM ARRAY
                itemArray.append(item.key)

                // ENTER DISPATCH GROUP
                dispatchGroup.enter()

                // USE ITEM.KEY TO GATHER IMAGE DATA
                Service.viewPicData(forKey: item.key) { (fruitItem) in
                        if let fruitItem = fruitItem {
                            imageDataDict[item.key] = [fruitItem]
                        }
                    // EXIT DISPATCH GROUP
                        dispatchGroup.leave()
                    }
            }

            // STORE ARRAY IN DICTIONARY UNDER FRUIT CATEGORY KEY
            imageMetaDict[categoryObject] = itemArray

        }

        // RETURN COMPLETION
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
            completion(imageMetaDict, imageDataDict)
        })
    })
}
```

Each dictionary looks similar to the following:

**imageMetaDict**

```
[
"apple": ["-LOM1R4EH9nszjJp0Va5", "-LOM1xnvKE6lc7fizomh", "-LOM1hSTmRY6wGrWMvIo", "-LOM1aRZT2XCE-6fvLBK"],
"pear": ["-LOLHakW-EtqevCeHfzl", "-LOM2DBGGuX5VQLmBz46"], 
"banana": ["-LOLmQWLXXyiCUwDBwID"], 
"orange": ["-LOM26_pm6lbJ1D6hVPB"]
]
```

**imageDataDict**

```
 [
 "-LOM26_pm6lbJ1D6hVPB": [myApp.FruitPicture(imageURL: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/1/image1", description: "pear 1")],
 "-LOM2DBGGuX5VQLmBz46": [myApp.FruitPicture(imageURL: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/1/image2", description: "banana 1")],
 "-LOLmQWLXXyiCUwDBwID": [myApp.FruitPicture(imageURL: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/1/image3", description: "apple 1")]
 ]
```

Is this on the right track with what you were suggesting?

From what I understand the next steps are:

1. Create an array of fruit.keys sorted alphabetically
2. Use the fruit.keys to get image.keys from 'imageMetaDict'
3. Use those image.keys to look up the image data (imageURL, etc) in 'imageDataDict'
4. Transform all of this data into a new FruitDict which contains fruitCategory -> [fruitObject]

Is this similar to what you were suggesting? I'm happy to hear any further pointers, code or suggestions you have, you've really helped me so far!

Answer (score 0):

To store images Create imageDict hash-map(dictionary) with the key you getting from firebase key in image->>fruits eg: "-LOLHakW-EtqevCeHfzl" with value you are getting or the stuct you already create, now when populating fruits-->apple get key from your bowl array or dict and then use that same key to get the image from imagesDict dict(hashmap you just create earlier

now while storing data in firebase make sure each image has unique keys and store that same key in your bowl-->apple->image that way it will be fast and easy to manage as image data and fruits data are mapped using key you get while storing new image :-) if you like the solution I can explain in more dept :-) #HappyCoding

Example

firebase node

```
"bowl" : {
        "apple" : {
            "-LOLHakW-EtqevCeHfzl" : true,
            "--LOLmQWLXXyiCUwDBwID" : false,
        }
    }


"image" : {
        "fruit" : {
            "-LOLHakW-EtqevCeHfzl" : {
                "description" : "round orange",
                "imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/1/image1"
            },
            "-LOLmQWLXXyiCUwDBwID" : {
                "description" : "big banana",
                "imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/1/image2"
            }
        }
    }
```

ImageDict

```
"-LOLHakW-EtqevCeHfzl":{
                        "description" : "round orange",
                        "imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/1/image1"
                       },
 "-LOLmQWLXXyiCUwDBwID" : {
                        "description" : "big banana",
                        "imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/1/image2"
                    }
```

or

```
{"-LOLHakW-EtqevCeHfzl":imageStruct1,
"-LOLmQWLXXyiCUwDBwID" :imageStruct2}
```

now to show image while populating apple

```
var keys = boul["apple"].allKeys;
if(boul["apple"][keys[0]]){ //value is true show image 
  var imageUrl = imageDict[keys[0]["imageURL"]; //if using dict
  //or
  var image = imageDict[key[0]].imageURL //if using struct

}
```

Now to store parent, categories and there image details 
create a Dict called fruitsDict or whatever with dict in side of another dict making key as fruite name eg: "apple":{apples Details like image price etc} but if you only interested in storing images just create list of images which have true value eg: "apple":[key1, key2...]; (keys you get from imageDict.

Now based on your requirement like

1. Show all category!! then create all category from fruitDict use that as datasource 
   and use imageDict and fruitsDict for details
2. Show only specific category like based on seasonal fruits then crate list of those fruits and show those based on imageDict and fruiteDict

   ## HappyCoding :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been very helpful! I've updated my original post with an edit including progress I've made. If you have the time, it would be great if you could check it out.